# How to play HTML5 videos fullscreen from within WKWebView (or WebView) on OS X

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, html5-video, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView in my cocoa application (OS X) that displays YouTube. Whenever I play a video (HTML5) and click on the fullscreen button, it says: "Full screen is unavailable.". How could I configure WKWebView to play HTML5 videos in fullscreen?

```
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm new to macOS and can't seem to

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988219/wkwebview-mac-browser-enable-fullscreen-html5/56998745#56998745 (note: You'll have to access private APIs)